# 「チェ」 「ちぇ」 外来語のみ ? -- How old is the interjection 「ちぇっ!」 ? ??

Tags: history, kana, interjections

[Why does ちょうし translate to "choushi"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/38401/why-does-%e3%81%a1%e3%82%87%e3%81%86%e3%81%97-translate-to-choushi)

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y%C5%8Don   >   Yōon or Youon (拗音?, contracted word or diphthong) is a feature of the Japanese language in which a mora is formed with an added [j] sound, i.e., palatalized.

ちゃ cha　　　 ちゅ chu 　　　ちょ cho

```
  --- This is odd.  This row doesn't include 「ちぇ」  as in チェ・ゲバラ
```

Ok, it's explained in the Jp Wikipedia page :

> 開拗音 == 開拗音は「あ行」と「わ行」を除く行のい段の仮名1文字に小文字の「ゃ」「ゅ」「ょ」のうちの1文字を付けて仮名2文字で表記される。 なお「シ」、「チ」または「ジ」に「ェ」を付けて表記される「シェ」「チェ」「ジェ」は対立する直音があるのでこれらを拗音に含めるとの考え方もあるが、外来語のみであることや部分的で音韻体系全般にわたるものでないことから拗音に含めない考え方もある。

but Wait ! , ... 「チェ」「ちぇ」  is in  外来語のみ ? ? ?    -- 
I find this hard to believe, because (e.g.) a very common interjection is

> ちぇっ!  - ［感］物事がうまくいかなかったときなどに発する声。また、舌打ちをする音。ちぇ。「ちぇっ、しようがないなあ」

Do 「チェ」 「ちぇ」 occur only in 外来語のみ ? ? ?

How old is the interjection  「ちぇっ!」 ? ? ?

( This page doesn't answer my questions: http://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/7765065.html )

Comment: you know that wikipedia is not written by specialists/ professionals, right?

Comment: ちぇっ is the closest possible transcription of the sound you write in English "tsk".

Answer (score 2):

> *Do 「チェ」 「ちぇ」 occur only in 外来語のみ ? ? ?*

No. There are very few and marginal occurrences in (Standard) Japanese, such as ちっ**ちぇ**え (vulgar form of [ちっちゃい](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/142019/meaning/m0u/)). Besides, the syllable is more widely used in some dialects, notably in some Kyushu dialects, しぇ [[ɕe]] and ちぇ [[tɕe]] systematically correspond to せ [[se]] and て [[te]] in Tokyo, respectively.

> *How old is the interjection 「ちぇっ!」 ? ? ?*

I think the majority of written ちぇっ！ is actually clicking *tsk* rather than pronounced as it's spelt, but putting that aside, the oldest appearance seems from 1778.

> **ちぇえ**
>
> **(2)** 残念な時くやしい時などに発することば。
>   ＊歌舞伎・金門五山桐〔１７７８〕四幕「仇な契りに畜生の、腹切れとて、お譲りはなされまいもの。チェエ」
>
> （日本国語大辞典）